# jQuery gallery with zoom in images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

I am creating a mobile website and need a gallery zoom the image and move the pictures by touch.

Unfortunately, I could not find anything like it in jQuery, just to [ios](http://codecanyon.net/item/dolphin-xml-ipadiphone-slideshowebook-template/336862).

If you know someone like a gallery, I will be very grateful :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an iOS like gallery plugin.

DEMO page http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/04-jquery-mobile.html

Author page http://www.photoswipe.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can change the width and height using J-Query, making it seem bigger.

```
$('#photo1').animate({
            width:300,
            height:300
});
```

You can use [Pixi](https://github.com/GoodBoyDigital/pixi.js/) for moving the pictures by touch, it comes with a handful of features and is touch screen compatible.